# JQuery selector for finding a nested span within a nested class is not working

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get the count of elements with a certain class beneath a parent or grandparent element but my selector is not working.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div id="adv0" class="collapse">
            <div class="advContent">
                <div class="editor-label measure">
                    <label for="Height">Height*</label>
                </div>
                <span class="field-validation-error" data-valmsg-for="Height" data-valmsg-replace="true"><span class="" for="Height">A height is required.</span></span>
           </div>
</div>
```

Here is the Jquery code I'm using:

```
var tabs = $('.collapse').not('.in');

    console.log("tabs.length: " + tabs.length);

    $(tabs).each(function () {

        console.log("number of errors: " + $(this).find('.field-validation-error').length);

        if ($(this).find('.field-validation-error').length > 0) {
            id = "#" + $(this).attr('id');
            $(id).collapse('show');
        }
    });
```

When I check the ID attribute of $(this), it returns "adv0", so I know $(this) is the proper starting point.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**

I've added the complete unedited HTML in case I missed something:

```
<div class="advGroup">
        <div class="advHeader" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#adv0"><a href="javascript:;"><i class="icon-chevron-down"></i>Physical properties <span class="advanced">(advanced)</span></a></div>
        <div style="height: auto;" id="adv0" class="in collapse">
            <div class="advContent">
                <div class="editor-label measure">
                    <label for="Height">Height*</label>
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field controls controls-row measure">
                    <input data-val-required="A height is required." class="input-small90 input-validation-error" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Height must be a number." id="Height" name="Height" placeholder="0" value="" type="text">
                    <select class="input-small122" id="HeightUnitId" name="HeightUnitId"              onclick="setHeightUnit()">
                      <option value="2">inches</option>
                      <option value="3">centimeters</option>
                      <option value="4">pixels</option>
                      </select>
                    <span class="field-validation-error" data-valmsg-for="Height" data-valmsg-replace="true"><span class="" for="Height">A height is required.</span></span>
                </div>

                <div class="editor-label measure">
                    <label for="Width">Width*</label>
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field measure">
                    <input data-val-required="A width is required." class="input-small90 input-validation-error" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Width must be a number." id="Width" name="Width" placeholder="0" value="" type="text"> <span class="MesureUnit">inches</span>
                    <span class="field-validation-error" data-valmsg-for="Width" data-valmsg-replace="true"><span class="" for="Width">A width is required.</span></span>
                </div>

                <div style="display: none;" class="editor-label depth">
                    <label for="Depth">Depth</label>
                    <a data-original-title="Depth" href="javascript:;" class="tip" data-toggle="popover" data-content="Applies to 3 dimensional products only. This would not apply to prints for example." title=""><i class="icon-info-sign"></i></a>
                </div>
                <div style="display: none;" class="editor-field depth">
                    <input class="input-small90" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Depth must be a number." id="Depth" name="Depth" placeholder="0" value="" type="text"> <span class="MesureUnit">inches</span>
                    <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Depth" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                </div>

                <div style="display: none;" class="editor-label weight">
                    <label for="Weight">Weight</label>
                    <a data-original-title="Weight" href="javascript:;" class="tip" data-toggle="popover" data-content="If you plan on using weight-based shipping then adding weight is mandatory for any non-print products." title=""><i class="icon-info-sign"></i></a>
                </div>
                <div style="display: none;" class="editor-field controls controls-row weight">
                    <input class="input-small90" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Weight must be a number." id="Weight" name="Weight" placeholder="0" value="" type="text">
                    <select class="input-small122" id="WeightUnitId" name="WeightUnitId">     <option value="1">ounces</option>
                     <option value="2">grams</option>
                    </select>
                    <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Weight" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**EDIT**

The following was added to show that the code is wrapped in a listener that fires when the form validator finds an error:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

   $("form").bind("invalid-form.validate", function () {
    clearTimeout(t);
    hideLoader();
    $('#formErrorNotice').show().delay(1500).fadeOut();

    var tabs = $('.collapse').not('.in');

    console.log("tabs.length: " + tabs.length);

    tabs.each(function () {
        var $this = $(this),
            thisErrors = $this.find('.field-validation-error'),
            thisId = '#' + $this.attr('id');

        console.log("current tab ID: " + thisId);
        console.log("number of errors: " + thisErrors.length);

        if (thisErrors.length) {
            $(thisId).collapse('show');
        }
    });
});
```

This line within the same block fires when it should:

```
$('#formErrorNotice').show().delay(1500).fadeOut();
```

So I believe this is firing at the proper time.

Comment: You want to show the validation errors?

Comment: Hi. I'm trying to open collapsed elements that have errors within them. In order to do that, I need to find the spans with errors, but the selector is not doing so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any problem with your code at the moment, let's reformat it a bit:

```
var tabs = $('.collapse').not('.in');

console.log("tabs.length: " + tabs.length);

tabs.each(function () {
    var $this = $(this),
        thisErrors = $this.find('.field-validation-error'),
        thisId = '#' + $this.attr('id');

    console.log("current tab ID: " + thisId);
    console.log("number of errors: " + thisErrors.length);

    if (thisErrors.length) {
        $(thisId).collapse('show');
    }
});
```

Or working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Rq8y7/

Does it work now? And what's the debug message in console after you run above code?

Comment: Thanks Hieu!
Debug says the following:tabs.length: 6
ppjs.js (line 60)
current tab ID: #adv0
ppjs.js (line 67)
number of errors: 0
ppjs.js (line 68)
current tab ID: #adv1
ppjs.js (line 67)
number of errors: 0

I am adding the complete HTMl block above in case I missed something. Previously I edited for readability.

Comment: Hmm this is weird. The fiddle with new HTML block works correctly as it should: http://jsfiddle.net/Rq8y7/1/. I'm wondering how do you generate the error in HTML? Perhaps it's rendered through JS after the previous code has run and that's the real problem here.

Comment: I don't think so, but I will try to test that. The function is created inside a listener that fires when the form validation fires with an error. I'll add the code above.

Comment: To check if there error message is there when the function is execute, you can do `console.log($this)` before debug the `thisId` above. Tell me if you could see the error message then. Also does `$('#formErrorNotice')` contain the error message?

Comment: Hi Hieu,
Thanks again for your help! You were right. Even though the errors exist, the validator had not written them to the page at that time. I wrapped the function in a setTimeout, and everything works as expected. I will try to find a more elegant answer and post it here.

Comment: Nice, you can try to fire it in the callback after validator renders the error then.

Answer (score 1):

So the issue was that the unobtrusive validator had not updated the error classes at the time the function was called, so getting the errors was not possible unless using a timeOut. Not a huge fan of timeouts, I looked deeper and found that the validator contains an errorMap property which shows the element and its error. Once I had the elements with errors, I could simply scan up to their parents and open the collapsed div, like so:

```
$("form").bind("invalid-form.validate", function (form, validator) {
    //expose errors in collapsed divs
    for (var i in validator.errorMap) {
        //console.log(i, ":", validator.errorMap[i]);
        target = $("#" + i).parents(".collapse");
        $(target).collapse('show');
    }      
});
```